# Variable from global scope not recognized in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's like this:

```
<script>
  var global_var = {foo:1};
</script>

<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

in myscript.js I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
  var global_var = typeof global_var == 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : global_var;
  console.log(global_var);    
});
```

But the global_var does not seem to be recognized in my 2nd script, even though I clearly defined it in the first, like a global variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/tYErg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the "var" in "var global_var" within your jQuery function. This is creating a different "global_var" variable within your function instead of using the true global. Drop this and your code works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've declared another `global_var` in the current scope. Either remove the `var` or change the variable name:

eg

```
global_var = typeof global_var == 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : global_var;
var other_var = typeof global_var == 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : global_var;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Mptw/

Answer (score 2):

You can't use two different variables with the same name from different scopes within the same scope. So when you declare your local `global_var` with the `var` keyword, your global becomes inaccessible.

If you need to make a local variable with the same name as a global you can use a closure like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    (function(global_var){
        // global_var is a local copy of global_var from the outer scope
        global_var = typeof global_var == 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : global_var;
        console.log(global_var);
    })(global_var);    
});
```

You can also refer to it as a property of the `window` object if you know it's global:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var global_var = typeof window.global_var == 'undefined' ? 
      {foo:2} : window.global_var;
    console.log(global_var);
});
```

Finally, if you don't want a local copy and just want to access the variable from the outer scope, then do not use the `var` keyword, since the purpose of that keyword is declaring a new variable:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    global_var = typeof global_var == 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : global_var;
    console.log(global_var);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining it without the `var` key work to make it in the global scope

```
<script>
     var global_var = {foo:1};
    </script>   

<script>    
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
      global_var = typeof global_var === 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : global_var;    
      alert(global_var.foo); // should be 1    
    });        
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tYErg/3/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
 global_var = typeof global_var == 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : global_var;
  console.log(global_var);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having this problem because you are declaring a local variable with the same name as your global variable, therefore the global variable is not visible any more.  You can still access it by explicitly specifying the scope:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
  var global_var = typeof window.global_var == 'undefined' ? {foo:2} : window.global_var;
  console.log(global_var);    
});
```